# I have delete the '.vscode-server' folder. But ssh-remote still dones't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

My system is `ubuntu 16.04`. 
It's fine when i use `ssh` in `terminal`.

But when i use `ssh-remove` in `vscode`. There's always error about `failed to ln vscode-remote-lock.root.xxxxx`. \

So i delete the whole `.vscode-server` folder (include itself).
However the error still occurs.

Here is the log

```
[21:45:22.437] Log Level: 2
[21:45:22.438] remote-ssh@0.51.0
[21:45:22.438] linux x64
[21:45:22.439] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+matrix5", attempt 1
[21:45:22.440] SSH Resolver called for host: matrix5
[21:45:22.440] Setting up SSH remote "matrix5"
[21:45:22.442] Acquiring local install lock: /tmp/vscode-remote-ssh-matrix5-install.lock
[21:45:22.450] Looking for existing server data file at /home/daijunjie/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-matrix5-a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0-0.51.0/data.json
[21:45:22.459] Using commit id "a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0" and quality "stable" for server
[21:45:22.464] Install and start server if needed
[21:45:22.477] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[21:45:22.484] > OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
[21:45:22.485] askpass server listening on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-66a057c15bb13b290ef0a13841206f52de4b6934.sock
[21:45:22.486] Spawning local server with {"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-2e95ed95f8d502946556d089375e3fc7c0a83a60.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","33509","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","matrix5"],"dataFilePath":"/home/daijunjie/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-matrix5-a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0-0.51.0/data.json"}
[21:45:22.486] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/home/daijunjie/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.51.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/home/daijunjie/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.51.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-66a057c15bb13b290ef0a13841206f52de4b6934.sock"}
[21:45:22.489] Spawned 13753
[21:45:22.570] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 13761
[21:45:22.571] stderr> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
[21:45:22.748] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:t5baR11kNfeoUNE2DkSopt8EuiL2Yw4Ki9KjcKoITiI
[21:45:22.889] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:22.889] stderr> 
[21:45:22.890] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:22.890] stderr> 
[21:45:22.891] stderr> 
[21:45:22.892] stderr> 
[21:45:22.892] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:22.893] stderr> 
[21:45:23.013] Got askpass request: {"request":"daijunjie@matrix5's password:"}
[21:45:23.014] Showing password prompt
[21:45:23.015] Listening for interwindow password on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-f7c76e17b4f9729a3485ae2ea663cb3b0ed9b124.sock
[21:45:23.015] Writing password prompt to globalState
[21:45:26.975] Got password response
[21:45:26.975] Interactor gave response: *********
[21:45:26.977] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[21:45:27.208] stderr> Authenticated to matrix5 ([172.16.30.205]:22).
[21:45:27.270] > Last failed login: Thu Sep  3 21:41:40 CST 2020 from 10.8.117.207 on ssh:notty
> There were 19 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
[21:45:27.682] > ready: fe8e17d6d674
[21:45:27.714] > Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015
[21:45:27.715] Platform: linux
[21:45:27.760] > fe8e17d6d674: running
[21:45:27.804] > Acquiring lock on /home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0
[21:45:27.806] > \ln /home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0.target /home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0
[21:45:27.810] > Installation already in progress...
> fe8e17d6d674##24##
[21:45:27.811] Received install output: fe8e17d6d674##24##
[21:45:27.812] Server installation process already in progress - waiting and retrying
[21:45:27.813] Terminating local server
[21:45:27.815] stderr> ln: 无法创建硬链接"/home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0": 文件已存在
[21:45:27.826] Local server exit: 15
[21:45:28.823] askpass server listening on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-306602990a24ee3d283dacc59c308749803f4079.sock
[21:45:28.824] Spawning local server with {"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-2b79fa3a864c0ae128b0977807dba070c415f490.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","33509","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","matrix5"],"dataFilePath":"/home/daijunjie/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-matrix5-a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0-0.51.0/data.json"}
[21:45:28.824] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/home/daijunjie/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.51.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/home/daijunjie/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.51.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-306602990a24ee3d283dacc59c308749803f4079.sock"}
[21:45:28.836] Spawned 13775
[21:45:28.925] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 13783
[21:45:28.926] stderr> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
[21:45:29.104] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:t5baR11kNfeoUNE2DkSopt8EuiL2Yw4Ki9KjcKoITiI
[21:45:29.248] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:29.248] stderr> 
[21:45:29.248] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:29.249] stderr> 
[21:45:29.249] stderr> 
[21:45:29.249] stderr> 
[21:45:29.250] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:29.250] stderr> 
[21:45:29.376] Got askpass request: {"request":"daijunjie@matrix5's password:"}
[21:45:29.377] Showing password prompt
[21:45:29.377] Listening for interwindow password on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-16359f8f4e6c647b4da0a31ef6ce7a8f10a2f8a8.sock
[21:45:29.377] Writing password prompt to globalState
[21:45:32.725] Got password response
[21:45:32.726] Interactor gave response: *********
[21:45:32.727] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[21:45:33.007] stderr> Authenticated to matrix5 ([172.16.30.205]:22).
[21:45:33.069] > Last failed login: Thu Sep  3 21:41:40 CST 2020 from 10.8.117.207 on ssh:notty
> There were 19 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
[21:45:33.519] > ready: fe8e17d6d674
[21:45:33.552] > Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015
[21:45:33.553] Platform: linux
[21:45:33.597] > fe8e17d6d674: running
[21:45:33.642] > Acquiring lock on /home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0
[21:45:33.644] > \ln /home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0.target /home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0
[21:45:33.646] > Installation already in progress...
> fe8e17d6d674##24##
[21:45:33.647] Received install output: fe8e17d6d674##24##
[21:45:33.647] Server installation process already in progress - waiting and retrying
[21:45:33.648] Terminating local server
[21:45:33.649] stderr> ln: 无法创建硬链接"/home/daijunjie/.vscode-server/bin/a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0/vscode-remote-lock.root.a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0": 文件已存在
[21:45:33.661] Local server exit: 15
[21:45:34.658] askpass server listening on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-a481e1d41215dd72b1bfcec1ef65bf61e8af3a6f.sock
[21:45:34.659] Spawning local server with {"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-4a56ac9a4aefb156178058c9abf0f67b32b2ae5d.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","33509","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","matrix5"],"dataFilePath":"/home/daijunjie/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-matrix5-a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0-0.51.0/data.json"}
[21:45:34.659] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/home/daijunjie/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.51.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/home/daijunjie/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.51.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-a481e1d41215dd72b1bfcec1ef65bf61e8af3a6f.sock"}
[21:45:34.672] Spawned 13797
[21:45:34.765] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 13805
[21:45:34.766] stderr> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
[21:45:34.945] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:t5baR11kNfeoUNE2DkSopt8EuiL2Yw4Ki9KjcKoITiI
[21:45:35.088] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:35.090] stderr> 
[21:45:35.090] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:35.090] stderr> 
[21:45:35.091] stderr> 
[21:45:35.091] stderr> 
[21:45:35.093] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available
[21:45:35.093] stderr> 
[21:45:35.217] Got askpass request: {"request":"daijunjie@matrix5's password:"}
[21:45:35.217] Showing password prompt
[21:45:35.217] Listening for interwindow password on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-43041326a96864945a076333ad00ca828d430d5f.sock
[21:45:35.217] Writing password prompt to globalState
[21:45:36.737] Password dialog canceled
[21:45:36.737] Interactor signaled cancel
[21:45:36.737] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[21:45:36.778] stderr> Permission denied, please try again.
[21:45:36.851] Got askpass request: {"request":"daijunjie@matrix5's password:"}
[21:45:36.887] stderr> Permission denied, please try again.
[21:45:36.950] Got askpass request: {"request":"daijunjie@matrix5's password:"}
[21:45:36.986] stderr> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
[21:45:36.986] > local-server> ssh child died, shutting down
[21:45:36.989] Local server exit: 0
[21:45:36.989] Received install output: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:t5baR11kNfeoUNE2DkSopt8EuiL2Yw4Ki9KjcKoITiI
No Kerberos credentials available

No Kerberos credentials available



No Kerberos credentials available

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

[21:45:36.990] Resolver error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
[21:45:36.993] ------
```

I'm so confused about it. Has any run into this problem? 
Is there any 'clean' way to reinstall `ssh-remote`?

Comment: I have the same error. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Remote-SSH version. After many attempts at trying to fix this for me, I found that downgrading Remote-SSH on VScode from 0.65.4 to 0.51.0 resolved the issue.
(User mileage may vary)